# sed: struggling with substitution and regex for ^*=

Tags: regex, sed

I am running a linux bash script. From stout lines like: `/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1`, I want to keep only the end of line after =.

I am struggling to understand why the following **sed** command is not working as I expect:

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | sed -e "s/^*=//"
```

*(I also tried)*

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | sed -e "s/^*\=//"
```

The return is always `/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1` and not `MyTrack1`

Comment: You need to use `.*` to match any 0+ chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | sed -e "s/^.*=//"
MyTrack1
```

The regular expression `^.*=` matches anything up to and including the last `=` in the string.

Your regular expression `^*=` would match the literal string `*=` at the start of a string, e.g.

```
$ echo "*=/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | sed -e "s/^*=//"
/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1
```

The `*` character in a regular expression usually modifies the immediately previous expression so that zero or more of it may be matched.  When `*` occurs at the start of an expression on the other hand, it matches the character `*`.

Answer (score 4):

An even simpler way if this is the only structure you are concerned about:

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | cut -d = -f 2
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful for this case. Struggling with sed, I had forgotten the cut command.

Answer (score 3):

Simply try:

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | sed 's/.*=//'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With another `sed`.

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | sed 's/\(.*=\)\(.*\)/\2/'
```

***Explanation:*** As per OP's request adding explanation for this code here:

`s`: Means telling `sed` to do substitution operation.

`\(.*=\)`: Creating first place in memory to keep this regex's value which tells `sed` to keep everything in 1st place of memory from starting to till `=` so text `/gpx/trk/name=` will be in `1` place.

`\(.*\)`: Creating 2nd place in memory for `sed` telling it to keep everything now(after the match of 1st one, so this will start after `=`) and have value in it as `MyTrack1`

`/\2/`: Now telling `sed` to substitute complete line with only 2nd memory place holder which is `MyTrack1`

***Solution 3rd:*** Or with `awk` considering that your Input_file is same as shown samples.

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'
```

***Solution 4th:*** With `awk`'s `match`.

```
echo "/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1" | awk 'match($0,/=.*$/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

Comment: Request you to please explain the second sed a little

Comment: @Inder, please check my explanation now and let me know if this helps you??

Answer (score 2):

Not to take you off the `sed` track, but this is easy with Bash alone:

```
$ echo "$s"
/gpx/trk/name=MyTrack1
$ echo "${s##*=}"
MyTrack1
```

The `##*=` pattern removes the maximal pattern from the beginning of the string to the last `=`:

```
$ s="1=2=3=the rest"
$ echo "${s##*=}"
the rest
```

The equivalent in `sed` would be:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^.*=(.*)/\1/'
the rest
```

Where `#*=` would remove the minimal pattern:

```
$ echo "${s#*=}"
2=3=the rest
```

And in `sed`:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^[^=]*=(.*)/\1/'
2=3=the rest
```

Note the difference in `*` in Bash string functions vs a sed regex:

1. The `*` in Bash (in this context) is glob like - itself means 'any character'
2. The `*` in a regex refers to the previous pattern and for 'any character' you need `.*`

Bash has extensive string manipulation functions. You can read about Bash string patterns in [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations and especially the notes